# how do I line up the dates on months with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am displaying data that has dates on the x axis and a scalar on the y axis.

I am getting the following display:

[image]

the code is the following:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10), constrained_layout=True)

date_from = kwargs.get('date_from', df['date'][0])
date_to   = kwargs.get('date_to', df['date'][len(df) - 1])
ax.set_xlim([date_from, date_to])

ax.plot(df['date'], df['close'], color='darkorange', zorder = 0)

ax.set_ylabel('USD')

ax.autoscale()
fig.autofmt_xdate()    

plt.show()
```

Questions:

- Why does it show me the 22 of each month? (and how to remove that). I'd like to show each month (just month-year) on the first and have a sub-tick per week
- is it possible to use the whole width for the graph instead of having margins?

---

Edit:

Following the suggestion in the first comment, I have added this:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%b '%y"))
```

and the output now looks like that:

[image]

which is much better.

about the second question: how do I remove the margins on the x-axis?

additionally, is there a way to put 'ticks' to split the months into 4 periods to loosely represent weeks?

like a non ugly version of this:

[image]

Comment: I believe this will not happen in the upcoming matplotlib 3.2. For now, you can use a `MonthLocator`

Comment: `ax.margins`. For the ticks, you can use minor ticks, and a `DayLocator`.

Comment: I can do: ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(DayLocator(interval=7)), but what formatter should I use to draw ticks? I tried the NullFormater() but I don't see anything displayed even though this link: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html seems to say this is the one to use.